# I want to display a loader while I download a file through a C# controller method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, onbeforeunload

I want to display a loader while I download a file. I am calling a method "DownloadFile" in my controller, it works properly. I tried to use the "onbeforeunload" Javascript trigger to display my loader. It works super fine on the all website but I have a problem with the download. It call a method in a controller, so the window expects a View to be returned. I am returning a File() so the loader is looping to the infinite and never stops, even when the file is downloaded !

I have tried several Javascript/Jquery triggers but none of them worked. Do you have any idea of how to trigger the end of a C# method execution to stop the display of the loader ?

Javascript :

```
  $(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
        displayBusyIndicator();
    });
```

Display busy indicator :

```
function displayBusyIndicator() {
$("#AjaxLoader").show();
}

function hideBusyIndicator() {
$("#AjaxLoader").hide();
}
```

C# :

```
    public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> DownloadCertificates([FromQuery]string certificateName)
    {
        // instantiate a CertficatesService Class which contains key vault client connexion
        CertificatesService service = new CertificatesService();
        // Instantiates download service
        Download download = new Download();

        // Instantiates memory stream object
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

        var user = await Dynamic365APICalls.getClientInformation(Request.Headers["X-Ms-Client-Principal-Name"], config.Value.Dynamic365ApiUrl, config.Value.EspaceClientSubKey);

        if (user.Value[0].Mobilephone.ToString() != null)
        {
            var SASToken = SASManager.GetAccountSASToken(config.Value.StorageConnection);

            // Gets the client certificates using session variable stored during landing page connexion
            // which contains the company name of the client

            CertificatePasswordModel certificatePassword = await service.GetCertificatePassword(certificateName, config.Value.ApiKeyVaultUrl, config.Value.EspaceClientSubKey);


           service.SendPasswordBySMS(user.Value[0].Mobilephone.ToString(), certificatePassword.Password, config.Value.TwilioAccount, config.Value.TwilioAuthToken, config.Value.TwilioAccountPhoneNumber);

            var fileStream = await download.DownloadFile(SASToken, config.Value.AccountName, certificateName, config.Value.StorageConnection, config.Value.PFXContainer);
            await fileStream.DownloadToStreamAsync(ms);
            System.IO.Stream blobStream = fileStream.OpenReadAsync().Result;

            return File(blobStream, fileStream.Properties.ContentType, certificateName + ".pfx");
        }
        else
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("Please enter your mobile phone to access this service");
        }

    }
```

I expect the loader to be diplayed during the download and to stop when download ends

Comment: When are you calling `$("#AjaxLoader").hide();`. Nothing in your code examples indicate you ever call that, hence the loader won't ever disappear

Comment: Hey @Tseng thanks for your time. In fact I don't know how to trigger the end of my C# Downloadfile method execution in Javascript to call .hide(). That's the problem !

Comment: And how are you initializing the download? Ajax/JavaScript?

Comment: @Tseng I am calling a controller method :

Comment: <a class="AllButton" id="download" asp-controller="Certificates" asp-action="DownloadCertificates" asp-route-certificateName="@certificate.Identifier.Name">Download</a>

Comment: That's not going to work. You are doing a new request and hence leaving the previous page. There is no way to catch that up unless you perform the download via JavaScript

Comment: Okay ... Sad but I will Javascript that stuff then :) @Tseng thanks for your time ! Have a nice day !

Comment: That's how the internet/www/http works. http is a stateless protocol. But since you're calling a direct url, the browser should actually get a download dialog and show the progress (i.e. chromes download bar)

Comment: @Tseng: That's not necessarily true. If the action returns with a `Content-Disposition: attachment` header, then it will pop a download dialog and not leave the page.

Comment: @ChrisPratt: But you still can't catch that event form JavaScript (which would be necessary to hide the loading spinner)

Comment: What event? The click? Why can't you? - Oh NM, you mean when the download completes, which there isn't even an event for.